# how to move Sksprite node with core motion? (sprite kit)

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, core-motion

I want to move a sk-sprite node in sprite kit using core motion. 
I want it will be like in the game tilt2live. I mean that I want to tilt the device in order to change the node position. 
how can I do it? 
thanks.

Comment: And I want a caramel chocolate egg for Easter. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: i try with this -(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add the CoreMotion framework to your project

[image]

2) Use the basic sample code to move a SKSpriteNode using CoreMotion.

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@implementation GameScene {
    CMMotionManager *motionManager;
    CMDeviceMotion *devMotion;
    SKSpriteNode *node0;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];

    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
    [motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:1.0/30.0];
    devMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;

    node0 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
    node0.position = CGPointMake(300, 300);
    node0.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node0.size];
    node0.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    node0.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [self addChild:node0];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    CMDeviceMotion *currDeviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;
    //NSLog(@"Roll Pitch and Yaw are %f, %f, %f",currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll, currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch, currDeviceMotion.attitude.yaw);

    // update position using CGPointMake
    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch > 0.10) {
        node0.position = CGPointMake(node0.position.x+1, node0.position.y);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch < -0.10) {
        node0.position = CGPointMake(node0.position.x-1, node0.position.y);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll > 0.10) {
        node0.position = CGPointMake(node0.position.x, node0.position.y+1);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll < -0.10) {
        node0.position = CGPointMake(node0.position.x, node0.position.y-1);
    }

    /*
    // update position using CGVectorMake
    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch > 0.10) {
        node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx+10, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
        // set speed limit of 100
        if(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx > 100)
            node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(100, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.pitch < -0.10) {
        node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx-10, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
        // set speed limit of 100
        if(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx < -100)
            node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-100, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll > 0.10) {
        node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy+10);
        // set speed limit of 100
        if(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy > 100)
            node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 100);
    }

    if(currDeviceMotion.attitude.roll < -0.10) {
        node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx, node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy-10);
        if(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dy < -100)
            node0.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(node0.physicsBody.velocity.dx, -100);
    }
    */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-airplane-game-with-sprite-kit-project-setup--mobile-19891) on Tuts+ which demonstrates the use of the accelerometer in a SpriteKit game. The highlights of what you will have to do are as follows:

First, import the CoreMotion library:

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

Declare a CMMotionManager property for the scene

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
```

In the `-initWithSize:` method, instantiate the motion manager

```
//CoreMotion
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .2;

[self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                         withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                         [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                         if(error)
                                         {
                                             NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                         }
}];
```

You will start getting accelerometer data to the `outputAccelertionData:` method along the x and y axes.

Use that to move your node around.